# cache-money requires Ruby version >= 1.8.7. any wayout to work with 1.8.6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I am having performance issue in my application I want to use memcache I am using ruby version 1.8.6. Can anyone suggest me best way out. I want something similar to cache-money or any wayout using 1.8.6 I can use cache-money